# How to get MouseEvents, even outside of a "window" (JPanel, or JFrame)

Tags: java

I want to get all mouse events(mainly click events), but I don't want to have a window (at least not a visible one);
I'm using this to collect data from a game, and thus don't want to block the vison of the game.

Comment: I'd say that this is not possible with vanilla Java. Some JNI may be necessary here.